# last item in list overwrites others in recycler view item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am parsing several JSONs to populate a cardview. Problem is 4 of them work just fine but one just seems to overwrite all the others instead of appending.
[image]

Check the doctor data from the screenshot.It repeats the last added doctor(Sylvester). I did a toast to see if the data from the model is correct and as you can see, it toasts all the different doctors correctly. What could the problem be.
Here is the bind viewholder class:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final AppointmentsAdapter.myViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
        appointmentsModel = new AppointmentsModel();
        appointmentsModel = appointmentsModelList.get(position);

        myViewHolder.appointments_date_TV.setText(appointmentsModel.getDate());
        myViewHolder.appointments_subject.setText(appointmentsModel.getSubject());
        myViewHolder.appointments_time.setText(appointmentsModel.getTime());
        myViewHolder.appointments_hospital.setText(appointmentsModel.getHospital());
        myViewHolder.appointments_doctor.setText(appointmentsModel.getDoctor());

        myViewHolder.appointments_county.setText(appointmentsModel.getCounty());
        myViewHolder.appointments_specialization.setText(appointmentsModel.getSpecialization());
        myViewHolder.denied.setText(appointmentsModel.getStatus());
        myViewHolder.pending.setText(appointmentsModel.getStatus());


        myViewHolder.approved.setText(appointmentsModel.getStatus());

        myViewHolder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // showPopupMenu(myViewHolder.overflow);
                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, myViewHolder.overflow);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.card_view_options);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_chat:
                                //get doctor id from sqlite
                                HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
                                String loggedInPatient= user.get("id");

                                //get specifics patient id from the model
                                String clickedDoctor = appointmentsModel.getDaktari();


                                //pass them to the chats activy to initiate chats for this particular patient
                                //with this particular doctor
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ChatsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("doctor", clickedDoctor);
                                intent.putExtra("patient",loggedInPatient);
                                ctx.startActivity(intent);

                                break;
                            case R.id.action_delete:
                                String doctorPhone = appointmentsModel.getPhoneNumber();
                                Intent intent2 = new Intent(ctx, MakePhoneCall.class);
                                intent2.putExtra("phone", doctorPhone);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });



        String a = appointmentsModel.getStatus().toString();

        if (a.contains("approved")) {
            myViewHolder.approved.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.pending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.denied.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        } else if (a.contains("declined")) {
            myViewHolder.denied.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.pending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.approved.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        } else if (a.contains("pending")) {
            myViewHolder.pending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.approved.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.denied.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }


        int len = appointmentsModel.getDate().length();
        String to_cut = appointmentsModel.getDate().substring(0, 10);

        myViewHolder.appointments_date_TV.setText(to_cut);


    }
```

And here is the class that fetches the JSONs and parses each of them: The last for loop is the one the JSON in question.

```
 private void postLoginDetails(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the requestl
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";


        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Configs.URL_LOGIN +Configs.LIST_APPOINTMENTS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                try {
                    appointmentsList = new ArrayList<>();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myAppointments");
                    JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myDoctor");
                    JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myCounty");
                    JSONArray jsonArray4 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("mySpecialization");
                    JSONArray jsonArray5 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myHospital");

                    if(jsonArray.length()<1 || jsonArray2.length()<1 ||jsonArray3.length()<1 ||jsonArray4.length()<1 ||jsonArray.length()<1) {
                        appointmentsList.clear();
                        no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else if( jsonArray.length()>0) {
                        if (no_data.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }


                    for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        appointmentsModel = new AppointmentsModel();
                        appointmentsModel.setDate(data.getString("appointmentDate"));
                        appointmentsModel.setTime(data.getString("time"));
                        appointmentsModel.setSubject(data.getString("subject"));
                        appointmentsModel.setStatus(data.getString("status"));
                        appointmentsList.add(appointmentsModel);

                        for (int b = 0; b < jsonArray5.length(); b++) {
                            JSONObject data5 = jsonArray5.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setHospital(data5.getString("hospitalName"));
                        }

                        for (int c = 0; c < jsonArray3.length(); c++) {
                            JSONObject data3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setCounty(data3.getString("countyName"));
                        }
                        for (int d = 0; d < jsonArray4.length(); d++) {
                            JSONObject data4 = jsonArray4.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setSpecialization(data4.getString("specializationName"));
                        }
                        for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray2.length(); a++) {
                            JSONObject data2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(a);
                            appointmentsModel.setDoctor(data2.getString("firstName"));
                            //Toast to test if data set is okay
                            String test = data2.getString("firstName");
                            Toast.makeText(Appointments.this,test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                        }


                    }



                    appointmentsAdapter = new AppointmentsAdapter(Appointments.this,appointmentsList);

                    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Appointments.this);
                    appointments_RV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    appointments_RV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    appointments_RV.setAdapter(appointmentsAdapter);
                    appointments_RV.setSaveEnabled(true);
                    appointments_RV.setSaveFromParentEnabled(true);
                    appointmentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    System.out.print("error" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to login_url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("action", "login");

                return params;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Here is the layout for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="#e9dedbdb"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"

        >




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_contents"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Subject : "
                            android:textColor="@color/artson_blue"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/appointments_subject__TV"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Diabetes Check up"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/card_view_overflow"
                            android:src="@drawable/blueoverflow"
                            android:paddingRight="20dp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Date : "
                            android:textColor="@color/artson_blue"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appointments_date_TV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:text=" 12.04.2017"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Time : "
                            android:textColor="@color/artson_blue"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appointments_time_TV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text=" 11:00 AM"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Hospital : "
                            android:textColor="@color/artson_blue"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appointments_hospital_TV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text=" Hema"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" ("
                            android:textColor="#000"
                             />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/appointments_county_TV"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=")"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Doctor : "
                            android:textColor="@color/artson_blue"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appointments_Doctor_TV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text=" Dr. Haji"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" ("
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/appointments_specialization_TV"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=")"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>




                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_pending"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_pending"
                        android:text="Pending"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_contents" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_approved"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:background="@drawable/button_approved"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:text="Approved"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_contents"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_declined"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_declined"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:text="Declined"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_contents"/>






        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and the onCreateViewHolder

```
 public AppointmentsAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View my_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appointments_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new myViewHolder(my_view);
    }
```

Comment: share your layout.xml with question

Comment: Can you post your `onCreateViewHolder()` method ?

Comment: I have added the method.

Answer (score 1):

Add this statement:

```
 appointmentsList.add(appointmentsModel);
```

after last inner for loop. Like this:

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        appointmentsModel = new AppointmentsModel();
                        appointmentsModel.setDate(data.getString("appointmentDate"));
                        appointmentsModel.setTime(data.getString("time"));
                        appointmentsModel.setSubject(data.getString("subject"));
                        appointmentsModel.setStatus(data.getString("status"));

                        for (int b = 0; b < jsonArray5.length(); b++) {
                            JSONObject data5 = jsonArray5.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setHospital(data5.getString("hospitalName"));
                        }

                        for (int c = 0; c < jsonArray3.length(); c++) {
                            JSONObject data3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setCounty(data3.getString("countyName"));
                        }
                        for (int d = 0; d < jsonArray4.length(); d++) {
                            JSONObject data4 = jsonArray4.getJSONObject(i);
                            appointmentsModel.setSpecialization(data4.getString("specializationName"));
                        }
                        for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray2.length(); a++) {
                            JSONObject data2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(a);
                            appointmentsModel.setDoctor(data2.getString("firstName"));
                            //Toast to test if data set is okay
                            String test = data2.getString("firstName");
                            Toast.makeText(Appointments.this,test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                        }
// add appointment here
appointmentsList.add(appointmentsModel);


                    }
```

Comment: I hade done that and it creates the views multiple times now such that instead of 6 viewholders,  there are now 12

Comment: you need to remove this appointmentsList.add(appointmentsModel); from top and add it after last for loop

Comment: That still doesn't work. It is in the same scope after all.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

I was passing the wrong parameter in the `getJSONObject`

```
for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray2.length(); a++) {
                            JSONObject data2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(a);
```

It should be

```
for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray2.length(); a++) {
                            JSONObject data2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);
```

Note the a instead of i from the parent for loop..

Thanks all for help.